# How do I take a screenshot and write to a file in intern javascript testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, screenshot, intern

I'm using http://theintern.io/ to do browser functional testing. How do I take a screenshot and save it to a file ?

Here is what I have

```
var fs = require('fs'); /* returns exception */
...
return this.remote
  .get(require.toUrl(url))
  .takeScreenshot(function(data) {
    fs.writeFile(filename, data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,''), 'base64', function(err) {if(err) throw err; });
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look to this answer, maybe it could be a better solution if you intend to have a screenshot for all your failed test: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39902615/2700879

Answer (score 1):

A working example for you, including using the dojo node helper for getting fs:

```
define(
    [
        'intern!object',
        'intern/chai!assert',
        'intern/dojo/node!fs'
    ],
    function (registerSuite, assert, fs) {
        registerSuite(
            {
                name: 'basict',

                'screencap': function () {

                    var remote = this.remote;
                    var workflowUrl = "https://foo.com";

                    return remote
                        .setImplicitWaitTimeout(40000)
                        .get(workflowUrl)
                        .takeScreenshot()
                        .then(function(data) {
                                fs.writeFileSync("/Users/whatever/myfile.png", data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,''), 'base64');
                        })
                        .end()
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote interface is promises-based, not callback-based, so you need to call `then` after the call to `takeScreenshot` to get the error. You also need to use the synchronous version of `fs.writeFile` unless you create and return a promise; throwing an error from the callback of `fs.writeFile` will just go into the abyss:

```
return this.remote
  .get(url)
  .takeScreenshot()
  .then(function(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,''), 'base64');
});
```